# R: dpois not returning correct probabilities?

Tags: r

I am working with dataset of the number of truffles found in 288 search areas. I am planning to test the null hypothesis that the truffles are distributed randomly, thus I am using `dpois()` to to calculate the expected probability densities. There are 4 categories (0, 1, 2, or 3 truffles per plot). The expected probabilities will later be converted to expected proportions and incorporated into a `chisq.test` analysis.

The problem is that the expected probabilities that I get with the following code don't make sense. They should sum to 1, but are much too small. I run the same exact code with another dataset and it produces normal values. What is going on here?

```
trufflesFound<-c(rep(0,203),rep(1,39),rep(2,18),rep(3,28))
trufflesTable<-table(trufflesFound)
trufflesTable

mean(trufflesTable)

expTruffPois<-dpois(x = 0:3, lambda = mean(trufflesTable)) 
expTruffPois
```

These are the probabilities it gives me, which are much too low!

0: 0.00000000000000000000000000000005380186

1: 0.00000000000000000000000000000387373404

2: 0.00000000000000000000000000013945442527

3: 0.00000000000000000000000000334690620643

In contrast, this dataset works just fine:

```
extinctData<-c(rep(1,13),rep(2,15),rep(3,16),rep(4,7),rep(5,10),rep(6,4),7,7,8,9,9,10,11,14,16,16,20)
extinctFreqTable <- table(extinctData)
extinctFreqTable

mean(extinctFreqTable)

expPois <- dpois(x = 0:20, lambda = mean(extinctFreqTable))
expPois

sum(expPois)
```

The sum is 0.9999997, which is close to the expected value of 1

Thoughts?

Comment: The probabilities are correct. You have a mean of 72, the probability of 0 comming from the population with mean 72 is close to 0.

Comment: Your probabilities are correct but I see what you are doing wrong. It seems like `trufflesFound` represents a random sample from Poisson. Then you calculated the frequency of the observations. But when you fit the Poisson distribution i.e. estimate the mean, why are you taking mean of the frequencies? You are supposed to take mean of the observations i.e. `mean(trufflesFound)`.

Comment: To elaborate on what @Onyambu said, the values you have in `trufflesTable` are the *number of observations* of each value, not the values themselves. So `mean(trufflesTable)` isn't very meaningful; maybe you wanted `mean(trufflesFound)`? The fact that you got close to 1 in the second case might just be a fluke or some other artifact of the sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda should be the average frequency, but taking `mean(trufflesTable)` returns the average of the counts of frequencies. Use `mean(trufflesFound)` instead. The reason the second one looks "right" is because `mean(extinctData)` is relatively close to `mean(extinctFreqTable)`.
Note that the probabilities don't sum exactly to 1, because given the mean it is conceivable that we'd observe more than 4 truffles in a future search area.

```r
trufflesFound<-c(rep(0,203),rep(1,39),rep(2,18),rep(3,28))
expTruffPois<-dpois(x = 0:3, lambda = mean(trufflesFound)) 
expTruffPois
#> [1] 0.57574908 0.31786147 0.08774301 0.01614715
sum(expTruffPois)
#> [1] 0.9975007
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Yup, that was dumb! Thanks for pointing it out!